# Saved Apple Maps locations in Guide keep sorting south to north

Tags: iphone, geolocation, maps

In saved locations in Guides in Apple Maps, there is a button to sort by Name, Distance or Date Added. If I click 'Distance' the locations are sorted by nearest distance to me.

But if I close the Apple Maps and open the app again, the saved locations in Guides are sorted south to north. How can I keep the locations sorted by Distance?

Comment: I’d recommend making a feature request. In my experience Apple always does simplistic things and doesn’t write software with full generality and usability or convenience in mind. Hopefully with more thoughtful requests like yours the community can advocate their software to become more powerful.